# Need suggestions with ActionBar, Navigation Drawer and back stack

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

I have an ActionBar activity. In this activity I have implemented Navigation Drawer from Android API.

One option of navigation drawer set a ListFragment with some elements inside its list.

When I click some elements I want to create a new fragment and set previous ListFragment to the stack. Also I want to destroy this new fragment by clicking ActionBar home button, in order to return to the previous ListFragment.

My problem comes here: When I click home button of the actionbar, drawer layout is displayed, instead of destroy the fragment... What should I do?

I have Overriden onOptionsItemSelected method in the fragment:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager()
                        .popBackStack();
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));

    }
```

Also I have set ListFragment to the backstack when Inflating the new fragment:

```
getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Comment: Are you using `ActionBarDrawerToggle`?

Comment: @ana 01 yes, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as the docs say [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28%29), popBackStack() is async. I suppose that the drawer layout is displayed because you call `super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)`.

I suggest you to return `true` for all cases you handle this selection by yourself (in this specific situation: `case android.R.id.home:`), and call `getActivity().onBackPressed()` (assuming that by pressing hardware back button the last fragment gets removed, as it should) instead of popping back stack directly. I've implemented a similar solution and it works for me.